# Image and ker of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is it true that given $A \in M_n(\Bbb R)$, if $X\in \operatorname{Ker}(A^T)$, then $X \in (\operatorname{Im}A)^\perp$ ?

Comment: What does ${}^t A$ mean?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk transposed of A (I’m French)

Comment: I presume you mean the transpose of $A$ by $^tA$. It is better to write $A^T$ and use `\operatorname{Im}A` and `\ker A^T` to get $\operatorname{Im}A$ and $\ker A^T$ respectively.

Comment: Do you know about adjoint linear transformations?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas: I don't agree. Bourbaki's notation is a prescript upshape t.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk maybe I do, as it is probably not called the same in French

Comment: I think this shoud not be true in general, self-adjoint operator and maybe some regularity on the scalar product you're dealing with.

Comment: @jacopoburelli It is true in general, this is a simple application of the fact that $A^T$ is the adjoint of $A$ with respect to the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk As i mentioned, you're taking the standard inner product indeed

Comment: @jacopoburelli Oh, I misunderstood your comment! My apologies. Though, since the question is phrased as "why is it true that ...", and OP seems to be a beginning linear algebra student, we ought to assume we're using the standard inner product.

Comment: Julien  You really need to read thoroughly and take to heart, and incorporate what you learn reading [How to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3998072/9003).  You're not going to last long with an account on this site if you don't begin to ask better questions than you have been.  The content of the questions is not the problem; the problem is that you tend to merely state the problem and expect others to do all the work for you, with no contribution, context, thoughts, effort, etc., on your part.  We are happy to help, but you have to do more to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*: the $i$-th entry of the vector $A^TX$ is the dot product of the $i$-th row of $A^T$ with $X$.